# Можно ли выполнить плагины Smarty до fetch и Display?

Tags: php, smarty

Предположим, есть шаблон вида

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>{$title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {mod name='news' limit='5' }
    </body>
  </html>
```

В основном коде

```
$smarty->assign('title', 'Заголовок');
$smarty->display('template.tpl');
```

Так вот вопрос - как из плагина переопределить переменную title, если он выполняется уже при отображении? Если делать сначала fetch, а затем Display - все все хорошо, но плагин выполняется дважды. Есть ли возможность сначала выполнить все плагины?

Comment: А если вызывать плагин до Display()?
То есть перенесите Display() в самый конец кода, а там пусть ваш плагин выполняется хоть 100 раз.

Comment: Вызов плагинов происходит в шаблоне. А выполняются, на сколько я понимаю, именно при Display() или Fetch().